# Using New-WebVirtualDirectory in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008

I need to create some virtual directories in several machines using a powershell script, but these machines have different Windows Server versions.

The oldest are **Windows Server 2008 R2** and I think that the cmdlet **New-WebVirtualDirectory** is only available since Windows Server 2012.

What can I do to be compatible from Windows 2008-R2 to 2019? I have not the control to upgrade these old servers neither their powershell versions...

I need the equivalent to this:

```
New-WebVirtualDirectory -Site "Default Web Site" -Application my_app -Name dir_name -PhysicalPath "D:\pyhiscal_dir"
```

Comment: Almost. That gave me clue. Thanks @Jawad, I will post an answer to explain the real alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jawad I found the perfect alternative compatible to every powershell versions.

```
PS> Import-Module webadministration
PS> New-Item 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\my_app\dir_name' -physicalPath "D:\pyhiscal_dir" -type VirtualDirectory
```

I found some examples in this site [Creating Websites, Web apps, Virtual Dirs and App Pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-creating-web-sites-web-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools)